# Multiple timer using countdown.js in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this project wherein I need to set a start button and when that start button is being triggered then it starts counting down and when the time is equal to 0 it will update the status. So I really don't know where to start it over since it is multiple data like this.

[image: When the start button is being triggered the time start counting down]

As shown above there when the start button is being triggered then the time for `shiatsu` will be `60 mins` and it starts counting down same through with `hot stone massage`.

**1.** How can I set the time using [countdown.js](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var austDay = new Date();           
          //how can i set 60 minutes time in here? should I format it like
          //austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear(), 12 , 0,60,0); ? 
            console.log(austDay);
            $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: +60});
        });
        </script>
```

**2.** How can I specify the service from my database? or when time's up how can I update the status record for a specific service?

I don't know what to do so where should I start? How to trigger the countdown event when time is up for me to be able to update the status? Please help!

Comment: can you post your HTML code first?